# Nesting if-then statements with wp-cli variables

Tags: wordpress, bash, if-statement, nested, wp-cli

I am using wp-cli and bash scripting to change WordPress home and siteurl database entries on multiple websites and want to automate it universally with this script. I normally just change it with either `wp option set home <newurl>` or just a global `wp search-replace <oldurl> <newurl> --parameter` and have to run an additional `wp elementor` command to change DB post content with Elementor. I'm using an inital `$URL` test to determine whether or not the home URL is a temporary domain (ex. [http://box1234.temp.domains/~username](http://box1234.temp.domains/%7Eusername)). To avoid mixed content errors from arising and since the majority of sites are using the Elementor plugin I want to also set up a test that will run and additional search-replace using the native Elementor wp-cli `wp elementor replace-urls <oldurl> <newurl>` but only need to run the command if Elementor is installed and active. My dilemma is that I'm gathering the oldurl and newurl from a variable set earlier in the script which may or may not be a temp domain name set by the host or just the http:// version of the domain and I need to nest an additional if-then-else statement to get this wp elementor command to run correctly but am not certain how to get it to work.

```
read -ep "Enter the domain: " DOMAINCOM ; 

URL=$(echo $(wp option get home | grep '~'));

if [ $URL] ; 
  then 
    wp search-replace $url https://$DOMAINCOM; 
    wp elementor replace-urls $URL https://$DOMAINCOM; 
  else 
    wp search-replace http://$DOMAINCOM https://$DOMAINCOM ; 
    wp elementor replace-urls http://$DOMAINCOM https://$DOMAINCOM 
fi
```

I need to add the below test to the above script to replace* the wp elementor commands in both the then and else statement to account for whether or not the home URL turns out to be a temp domain or not.

```
ELEMENTORCHECK=$(wp plugin status elementor | grep -i status | cut -d: -f2); 
if [ $ELEMENTORCHECK= Active ] ; 
  then 
    wp elementor replace-urls $url https://$DOMAINCOM; 
  else 
    echo "Elementor isn't installed" | grep Elementor ; 
fi ;
```

I don't think doing a
`if [ $URL ] && [ $ELEMENTORCHECK ]` or `if [ $URL ] || [ $ELEMENTORCHECK ]` would work and am not sure how to nest the tests using an elif statement without messing up the whole statement and need some guidance. Hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out:

```
if [ $URL ]
  then
    TEMPURL=$(wp option get home)
    wp search-replace $TEMPURL/ https://$DOMAINCOM/ --skip-columns=guid
    sed -i.bak "s#$TEMPURL#https://$DOMAINCOM#g" $(grep -irl "$TEMPURL")
    echo " 'wp search-replace' ran as well as 'sed' to change URLs from $TEMPURL to $DOMAINCOM " | grep 'wp search-replace\|sed\|$TEMPURL\|$DOMAINCOM'
    ELEMENTORCHECK=$(wp plugin status elementor | grep -i status | awk '{print $2}')
    if [ $ELEMENTORCHECK = Active ]
        then
          wp elementor replace-urls $TEMPURL https://$DOMAINCOM
        else
          echo "Elementor isn't installed or just isn't active" | grep Elementor
    fi
  else
    NOTTEMPURL=$(wp option get home)
    wp search-replace $NOTTEMPURL/ https://$DOMAINCOM/ --skip-columns=guid
    sed -i.bak "s#$NOTTEMPURL#https://$DOMAINCOM#g" $(grep -irl $NOTTEMPURL)
    echo " 'wp search-replace' ran as well as 'sed' to change URLs from $NOTTEMPURL to $DOMAINCOM " | grep 'wp-replace\|sed\|$NOTTEMPURL\|$DOMAINCOM'
    ELEMENTORCHECK=$(wp plugin status elementor | grep -i status | awk '{print $2}')
      if [ $ELEMENTORCHECK = Active ]
        then
          wp elementor replace-urls $NOTTEMPURL https://$DOMAINCOM
          echo "Elementor is installed and URLs were changed from $NOTTEMPURL to https://$DOMAINCOM using the command 'wp elementor replace-urls'" | grep -i elementor
        else
          echo "Elementor isn't installed or just isn't active" | grep Elementor
      fi
fi ;
```